# Installing ruby using RVM fails, without trace

Tags: ruby, rvm

Ok, I installed RVM. I tested using:

```
type rvm | head -n1
```

The output: "rvm is a function". So far so good.

Then I tried:

```
rvm install 1.8.7-p302
```

All went smoothly, but then:

```
$ ruby -v
The program 'ruby' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

RVM says all went fine through the install... Getting RVM info it says:

```
$ rvm info

ruby-1.8.7-p302:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux pi-ubuntu 2.6.32-24-generic-pae #43-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 16 15:30:27 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.0.11 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  ""
    version:      ""
    date:         ""
    platform:     ""
    patchlevel:   ""
    full_version: ""

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302"
    ruby:         "/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302"

  binaries:
    ruby:         ""
    irb:          ""
    gem:          ""
    rake:         ""

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/pi/bin:/home/pi/Programs/ZendFramework-1.10.6/bin:/home/pi/Programs/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/pi/.rvm/bin:/home/pi/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302:/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@global"
    BUNDLE_PATH:  "/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302"
    IRBRC:        "/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Also trying to set a default ruby fails:

```
$ rvm 1.8.7 --default
ruby ruby-1.8.7-p302 is not installed.
'rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p302'
```

How could I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks guys. rvm use ruby-1.8.7 says: warn: ruby ruby-1.8.7-p302 is not installed. To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p302'

Added info:

```
$ rvm list 

rvm rubies

$ rvm use ruby-1.8.7
warn: ruby ruby-1.8.7-p302 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p302'
```

About my .profile, I didn't use it, instead I used . bashrc. This is how it looks like:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
# [ -z "$PS1" ] && return

if [[ -n "$PS1" ]] ; then

#... all of the original content....

fi

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

---

Ok, at this point I tried moving:

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

to my .profile. No luck.

Also I reinstall a ruby, Once again all went smoothly:

```
$ rvm install 1.8.7-p302
/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #fetching 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #downloading ruby-1.8.7-p302, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 4086k  100 4086k    0     0  42600      0  0:01:38  0:01:38 --:--:-- 44324
ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #extracting ruby-1.8.7-p302 to /home/pi/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p302
ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #extracted to /home/pi/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p302
ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #configuring 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #compiling 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #installing 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #rubygems installing to ruby-1.8.7-p302
Retrieving rubygems-1.3.7
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  284k  100  284k    0     0  25693      0  0:00:11  0:00:11 --:--:-- 61417
Extracting rubygems-1.3.7 ...
ruby-1.8.7-p302 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem).
ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #importing default gemsets (/home/pi/.rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.8.7-p302 - #complete
```

But again doing ruby -v says is not installed...

I missed something, but I cannot figure it out...

Comment: what happens when you do `rvm use ruby-1.8.7`?

Comment: and what does `rvm list` say?

Comment: Did you put the appropriate line at the end of your .profile? rvm will not work without it.

Comment: Ok I'll add this info in my question. Thanks guys and look up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll help you in #rvm on irc.freenode.net if you are still stuck. I am in there during the day EST.

Comment: The answer is below, but Wayne helps me on irc.

Answer (score 5):

OK, some deps were broken, that was the problem.

I did:

```
apt-get install build-essential bison openssl libreadline5 libreadline-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev
```

Now rvm is working properly.

Thank u!

Answer (score 3):

It help for me. I add line to end of ~/.bashrc

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

and reload bash. Now work

rvm use 1.9.2 --default

ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 1):

I actually had the same problem. Turns out I had sudo bash'd into my console which killed it all. Need to install as the user... not under sudo. Nice 3 hours of time wasted! lol.

Pete.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by running:

```
rvm use ruby-1.8.7-p302
```

Comment: In fact to use it permanently I needed "rvm --default use 1.9.2"