# "The program 'ruby' is currently not installed" error after reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

After the reboot which was required to update all the packages,

```
ruby -v
```

doesn't work. It says rails is not installed either, but I guess it should be the similar issue. when I do:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

It says the newest version is already installed.
When I do:

```
dpkg -L ruby
```

I get the following output:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
[and other stuff..]
```

But I realized $PATH already includes /usr/bin:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin
```

May I know why I'm still getting the following error message?:

```
The program 'ruby' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

My .bashrc already has this too:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: Did you read [**THIS**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809294/installing-ruby-using-rvm-fails-without-trace)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dpkg will be checking in a database that it maintains, whereas trying to execute ruby uses the PATH. If I recall correctly, Ubuntu has a bash handler configured to execute when any command is unresolvable; it seems that it just displays that generic message rather than checking with dpkg first.

It is possible that ruby has disappeared from your filesystem (or at least the directory it previously resided in), or that your PATH was changed.

What do you get if you execute "which ruby" and "where ruby"?

Lastly, Ubuntu can complain that a program cannot be found when it is present. This occurs when running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, without the necessary x86 libraries installed, and trying to execute a 32-bit binary. However, I recall the error message being more along the lines of "file not found".

Comment: When I ran "which ruby", I got no output (nothing prints). I think maybe it has disappeared from the filesystem. I had to apt-get remove and installed again. I'm not sure what happened but I guess I have to set up everything all over again :( Thanks for your reply!